# How to uncover underbraces without unwanted text moves?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, underbrace, uncover

I'm trying to uncover underbraces, and I do not want distracting and annoying text moves, like in this example :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, bending, calc, fadings, hobby, positioning, shadows, shadows.blur, shapes, shapes.misc, tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$(2k+1)^2=(2k+1)(2k+1)=2k\!\times\!2k+2k\!\times\!1+1\!\times\!2k+1\!\times\!1$\\
    \pause
$\hphantom{(2k+1)^2}=4k^2+2k+2k+1 =
    \alt<2>{4k^2+4k+1}{{\underbrace{4k^2\onslide<3->}_{\text{pair}}+\underbrace{4k\onslide<3->}_{\text{pair}}+1}}$
    \pause

so $(2k+1)^2$ is also odd
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This renders to :
[image]

I can imagine tricks with box saving, measurement and \rule, or \hphantom, or opacity and \rlap, but this seems to be tricky and ungly solutions. Do you have some ideas to get an elegant solution ? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How about just replacing `\begin{frame}` by `\begin{frame}[t]`?

Comment: I don't know why (probably a font style or font size issue in the document I'm working on), but I still have a vertical shift. I'd also like to prevent horizontal shift - my question was probably not precise enough... sorry !